# how to replace subject(sub) to a secret string in id_token at the openid connect?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, yii2, openid, openid-connect

oauth2 library:

https://github.com/Filsh/yii2-oauth2-server

https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php

please notice that, user id in my system is a integer not a string.

my purpose just hide system user id.

the steps for id token :

http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/overview/openid-connect/

`{
  "iss": "localhost",
  "sub": 2,
  "aud": "-7IloKCawcvBwRijJeo7nsLxx1chC68L",
  "iat": 1514518157,
  "exp": 1514521757,
  "auth_time": 1514518157,
  "nonce": "dfsdsdsd"
}`

`md5('-7IloKCawcvBwRijJeo7nsLxx1chC68L' + 2) = 3C86CBBFF35AD3B6E609F5622D776531`

i wanna replace subject to md5(client_id + subject)

`{
  "iss": "localhost",
  "sub": "3C86CBBFF35AD3B6E609F5622D776531",
  "aud": "-7IloKCawcvBwRijJeo7nsLxx1chC68L",
  "iat": 1514516044,
  "exp": 1514519644,
  "auth_time": 1514516044,
  "nonce": "dfsdsdsd"
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF I understand your desire, the OpenID Provider can provide anything for the Subject as long as it is Unique at that OpenID Provider for a specific relying party.

OpenID Connect Identity Token Sub is a Subject Identifier is a locally unique and never re-assigned identifier within the Issuer for the Authenticated Entity, which is intended to be consumed by the OAuth Client.

[Two Subject Identifier types](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#SubjectIDTypes) (subject_types_supported) are defined by OpenID Connect and are Required to be present in the [OpenID Provider Metadata](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Openid-configuration):

**public** - provides the same sub (subject) value to all OAuth Client. It is the default if the provider has no subject_types_supported element in its discovery document.

**pairwise** - provides a different Sub value to each OAuth Client, so as not to enable OAuth Client to correlate the End-User's activities without permission.

The OpenID Connect Provider's OpenID Connect Discovery document SHOULD list its supported Subject Identifier types in the subject_types_supported element.

If there is more than one type listed in the array, the OAuth Client MAY elect to provide its preferred identifier type using the subject_type parameter during Registration.

Sub MUST NOT exceed 255 ASCII characters in length.

Sub Sub value is a Case-sensitive string.

Comment: thanks for you answer. 
sorry for my poor english, i cant description more clear. 
you answer it is useful for me. 
thanks very much. 

by the way, if you experienced this library, it is support "pairwise" function or no?

ps: how to input newline when i add a comment?

Comment: Put in a newline 
in a comment.
(I have not been able to figure it out either.) I did add some more information on how to determine the subject_types_supported the OpenID Provider Metadata